# Save the powershell result output on the user profile that runned the script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0

I have a script that checks, from a defined list, the disk space on our servers.

The initial disk.ps1 and the list.txt file will always be on "D:\scripts\disk.ps1, and I want to send the "result" html file on the Desktop of the user who runned the script.

I'm using the following line, but not sure if OK, did number of tests, but outcome is always an error in powershell.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\Disk-Report.html"
```

Here is my script :

```
# Simple HTML page displaying disk usage.

Param (
$computers = (Get-Content  "D:\Scripts\list.txt")
)

$Title="Hard Drive Report to HTML"

#embed a stylesheet in the html header
$head = @'
<style>
body { background-color:#dddddd;
       font-family:Tahoma;
       font-size:12pt; }
td, th { border:1px solid black;
         border-collapse:collapse; }
th { color:white;
     background-color:black; }
table, tr, td, th { padding: 2px; margin: 0px }
table { margin-left:50px; }
</style>

'@

#define an array for html fragments
$fragments=@()

#get the drive data
$data=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype=3" -computer $computers

#group data by computername
$groups=$Data | Group-Object -Property SystemName

#this is the graph character
[string]$g=[char]9608 

#create html fragments for each computer
#iterate through each group object

ForEach ($computer in $groups) {

    $fragments+="<H2>$($computer.Name)</H2>"

    #define a collection of drives from the group object
    $Drives=$computer.group

    #create an html fragment
    $html=$drives | Select @{Name="Drive";Expression={$_.DeviceID}},
    @{Name="SizeGB";Expression={$_.Size/1GB  -as [int]}},
    @{Name="UsedGB";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f (($_.Size - $_.Freespace)/1GB) }},
    @{Name="FreeGB";Expression={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) }},
    @{Name="Usage";Expression={
      $UsedPer= (($_.Size - $_.Freespace)/$_.Size)*100
      $UsedGraph=$g * ($UsedPer/2)
      $FreeGraph=$g* ((100-$UsedPer)/2)
      #I'm using place holders for the < and > characters
      "xopenFont color=Redxclose{0}xopen/FontxclosexopenFont Color=Greenxclose{1}xopen/fontxclose" -f $usedGraph,$FreeGraph
    }} | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment 

    #replace the tag place holders. It is a hack but it works.
    $html=$html -replace "xopen","<"
    $html=$html -replace "xclose",">"

    #add to fragments
    $Fragments+=$html

    #insert a return between each computer
    $fragments+="<br>"

} #foreach computer

#add a footer
$footer=("<br><I>Report run {0} by {1}\{2}<I>" -f (Get-Date -displayhint date),$env:userdomain,$env:username)
$fragments+=$footer

$Path = "C:\Users\%userprofile%\Desktop\Disk-Report.html"
#write the result to a file
ConvertTo-Html -head $head -body $fragments  | Out-File -filepath $Path
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$Path = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Disk-Report.html"
```

To call an environment variable in powershell use `$env:nameofthevariable`.

The `%nameofthevariable%` is for the `CMD/DOS`.